# Prevent email signature from being inserted when replying

Tags: macos, mail.app

Is there a way to prevent Mail.app on OS X from auto inserting your email signature when replying to a message?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can create a template for a new email (which would include you signature) and then leave signatures off everywhere else by setting our signature to none.

The template can be a draft message or a sent message. Either way you have the option of sending them again, which makes them de facto templates.

Answer (score 1):

With MacMail the only way to do this is to set the default to no signature, and then use a program like TextExpander to insert a signature for you.

You CAN do this in Mozilla Thunderbird however.

Good luck
B

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default signature or "None" for each mail account in Preferences -> Signatures

[image]

Comment: I want the signature to be auto inserted on new emails, but not when replying.